# Reasonable phobia name for fear of alcohol evaporating before you can drink it

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, terminology, phobias

I am curious as to what the phobia name would be for the fear of the alcohol in your drink evaporating before you can drink it.

It appears most phobias are rooted in Greek and sometimes Latin.  Some searching around turned up some names for a fear of alcohol:

```
Alcohol Phobia- Methyphobia or Potophobia.
```

Are there any language whizzes out there that can come up with this?

Alcoholism will not be accepted as an answer.

Comment: Why do you think there is a single word for that?

Comment: I have seen everything now. The morbid  fear of alcohol evaporating before you can drink it. Probably the best excuse used by an alcoholic ether!

Comment: In clinical psychology any anxiety producing fear that gets documented enough gets a phobia name, which is a singular word made up of the greek (latin?) roots.  @Centaurus

Comment: Well, it's obviously *alcovapophobia*!

Comment: I'll bet the DSM V doesn't mention that phobia.

Comment: Try **evapophobia***.

Comment: And you ask for *reasonable*? :) I'm not an expert but I would have thought alcohol takes a number of hours, if not days to evaporate, so if someone is terrified by the thought of drinking grape juice instead of wine, the *solution* is easily found.

Comment: RobC, I suggest you look it up in the DSM V.

Comment: *Evaporatophobia*, perhaps, based on the Latin roots of *[evaporate](https://www.google.com/search?q=etymology+evaporate)* (evaporare -> evaporat- = "changed into vapor"). *Alcohol* is of Arabic origin, but I suppose you could prefix it with *eth-* or *ethyl-* or something as a "hack" (note that drinking alcohol is *ethyl alcohol*, not *methyl*). People are generally [pretty liberal with their construction of -phobias](http://phobialist.com/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the fear of alcohol is, in fact, *[methyphobia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methyphobia)*, the fear of evaporating alcohol would be most precisely:

***methyexatmiphobia*** (since η is phonetically related to ἐ, some might prefer *methexatmiphobia*)

or more simply:

***methyatmiphobia***,

or simplest of all:

***methatmiphobia***:

The Greek word for *wine* is **μέθη**, while **ἐξάτμιση** is the Greek word for *evaporate*, and **ἀτμίς** is the Greek word for *vapor*.

---

Also ***Soberphobia***:

If it evaporates before you can drink it you can't stay drunk.

---

Comment: people have no essence of humour.. +1 from me

Comment: @Mari-LouA It's possible that others' essences of humor exist but differ from yours.

Comment: Superb work.  Think we can squeeze in the greek word for drink (toto)?  Maybe like methyatmitotophobia?

Comment: The fear of drinking evaporated alcohol? Or the fear of drunk alcohol evaporating? Fear alcohol the or evaporating drunk of? I think I've had one too many.

Comment: I hope you had them fast enough to avoid the evaporation of the alcohol.  I think I'm going to go with methatmiphobia for now.  I will make sure down the road when this becomes mainstream that it is attributed to you. @ScotM